# angular2 routerLink not display on url

Tags: angular, routes

Trying to create a SPA with angular2:

Inside my main module I declare the routes and the components that I am about to use:
**mainApp.ts:**

```
import { NgModule }      from '@angular/core';
import { BrowserModule } from '@angular/platform-browser';
import { RouterModule, Routes }  from '@angular/router';
import { BaseComponent,IndexComponent, ContactComponent, 
         PortfolioComponent, AboutComponent }  from './BaseComponents';

const appRoutes: Routes = [
  { path: '', component: IndexComponent },
  { path: 'about', component: AboutComponent },
  { path: 'portfolio', component: PortfolioComponent},
  { path: 'contact', component: ContactComponent}
];

@NgModule({
  imports:      [ BrowserModule, RouterModule.forRoot(appRoutes)],
  declarations: [ BaseComponent, IndexComponent, ContactComponent, 
                  PortfolioComponent, AboutComponent ],
  bootstrap:    [ BaseComponent ]
})
export class AppModule { }
```

So, it's clear that I bootstrap the **BaseComponent**
So inside the BaseComponent.ts I import the followings:

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
import { Routes, RouterModule } from '@angular/router';
import { IndexComponent, AboutComponent, PortfolioComponent, 
         ContactComponent} from '../BaseComponents';
```

and inside the template:

```
<a [routerLink]='index'>index</a>
<a [routerLink]='portfolio'>portfolio</a>   
<a [routerLink]='about'>about</a>
<a [routerLink]='contact'>contact</a>

<router-outlet></router-outlet>
```

If I type manualy inside the url, then I do navigate to the upper paths. But if I click on them, no reaction.. Debugger doesn't give any error-warning.

Any help is welcome!

Comment: Replacing like:  `<a [routerLink]='[index]'>index</a>` etc, gives me undefined http://imgur.com/a/EBmGc

Answer (score 3, accepted):

when you use `[routerLink]="index"` index must be a property  of your component.

```
<a [routerLink]="'index'">index</a>
<a [routerLink]="'portfolio'">portfolio</a>   
<a [routerLink]="'about'">about</a>
<a [routerLink]="'contact'">contact</a>
```

or

```
<a routerLink="index">index</a>
<a routerLink="portfolio">portfolio</a>   
<a routerLink="about">about</a>
<a routerLink="contact">contact</a>
```

or

```
<a routerLink='index'>index</a>
<a routerLink='portfolio'>portfolio</a>   
<a routerLink='about'>about</a>
<a routerLink='contact'>contact</a>
```

Comment: yes, this is it. It wasn't passed like a property. Thank you!